# Django import: Ignore created value from TimeStampedModel

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which is inherited from `TimeStampedModel` and I am trying to import data using Django `import_export`.

The imported data contains "created" column providing the datetime values which are different from current date time. The import is successful but it is using the created value from `TimeStampedModel` rather that the one from the file.

Is there anything that can be done in the `import_obj` function to override the `created` value from the `TimeStampedModel`?
The format of date time in the file is in the expected format and is one of the supported formats.

```py
class TestResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def import_obj(self, obj, data, dry_run):
        for field in self.get_fields():
            self.import_field(field, obj, data)
```

Object creation date is always the current `datetime` rather than the `datetime` in the imported file.

Comment: I ended up overriding `save_instance()` to achieve this